# Getting all the emails into a list using IMAP

Tags: dart, flutter, imap

I am trying to create an mail app in Flutter, right now I am testing the back end then I want to integrate it in my app.

I am using IMAP to get all my emails from my university and insert them into a list using a class called Emails with parameters like subject, date, from, to and body  (all string types).

```
    List emails;
  Future<EMails> getEmails() async {
    ImapFolder inbox = await client.getFolder("inbox");
    EMails list;
    for (var i = inbox.mailCount; i > 0; i--) {
      list.subject = await inbox.fetch(["BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]"],
          messageIds: [i]) as String; //gets the subject
      list.date = await inbox.fetch(["BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (Date)]"],
          messageIds: [i]) as String; //gets the Date
      list.from = await inbox.fetch(["BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (From)]"],
          messageIds: [i]) as String; //gets the From
      list.to =
          await inbox.fetch(["BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (To)]"], messageIds: [i])
              as String; //gets the To
      list.body = await inbox.fetch(["RFC822.TEXT"], messageIds: [i]) as String;
      emails.add(list);
    }
    return list;
  }
```

The problem is that I can't transform my fetching data into strings.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY2DF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.fetch returns a Future, but it looks like you're not waiting for it yet.  Add `await` in front of each `inbox.fetch`.

This is documented at https://pub.dev/documentation/imap_client/latest/imap_client/ImapFolder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

.fetch returns a Map>

```
Map<int, Map<String, dynamic>> subject =  await inbox.fetch(["BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]"],messageIds: [i]);

var mapSubjectEmail = subject[i];
var mapEmail = mapSubjectEmail.values;
var subjectEmail = mapEmail.first as String;
```